# Perform Typeahead at button click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead

I have an input field and a button next to it.

I do not want the typeahead to work immediately on pageload because there's a PHP curl page load associated with it and I don't want it to load on every new key press.

Instead a user should input his values into the textbox and then press the button.
Then the typeahead should do an ajax call to my php script which will do the curl request and return a json array with the fetched results.

I tried calling the `.typeahead` method on the button click but it doesn't work as I want it.
With this, the user still needs to type a letter in order for the typeahead to do the ajax call and for the box to appear and show the suggestions.

I would want it like this: The user inputs his value into the input box and presses the button. Then the typeahead should do the ajax call to the php script and immediately list the suggestions.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I know, this question is a bit old. I was also looking for a similar method and able to find a workaround.

typeahead assigns two classes to the list[ul] -- "typeahead" and "dropdown-menu".

```
<ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu" style="top: 304px; left: 176px; display: block;">
```

This changes to "display: none", when the list is hidden.

```
<ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu" style="top: 304px; left: 176px; display: none;">
```

I am able to show the list again by calling a simple JQuery "show()" on "dropdown-menu" class.

NOTE: I am using typeahead with bootstrap 2.3.1